# I cannot run micro in terminal although it is installed global

Tags: node.js

I tried https://github.com/zeit/micro
and unable to run npm start
I run micro in terminal and also see the error

I type in terminal "micro"
Response :
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/micro/bin/micro.js:33
let file = args.sub[0]
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations ...

[image: error while type micro]

Comment: And what is your question? Update Node to the latest version.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message looks as if you were using a version of Node.js that is not up-to-date. So, update your installation of Node.js, and everything should be fine.

Just in case you don't do that yet, have a look at the [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) which makes installing and managing different versions of Node.js a breeze. If you have installed it on your local system, installing the current version of Node.js becomes as easy as:

```
$ nvm install 7.5.0
```

(Or whatever the current version of Node.js is when you read this answer.)